# Gerir DataTable com muita informação

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desempenho, datatable

Tenho aqui um "pequeno" problema com um `DataTable`.

A partir de uma consulta SQL estou a obter uma quantidade enorme de registos (**> 1.000.000**), e apesar da consulta ser relativamente rápida, o carregamento do `DataTable` a partir do `Fill()` é extremamente lento e, em alguns casos, gera um erro de `System.OutOfMemoryException` porque o processo onde está a ser executado o código excede os **4Gb** (compilação obrigatória em x86).

A minha questão é se existe alguma forma de reduzir o tempo de carregamento do `DataTable` e, ao mesmo tempo, evitar que a memória exceda o limite.

De salientar que essa informação será utilizada posteriormente para serialização em XML.

Comment: Não usar DataTabel? :) Sério. Foram criadas outras tecnologias porque esta era problemática.

Comment: Pois, se efetivamente não houver outra hipótese talvez tenhamos que mudar! Será que utilizando um `DataReader` e ir preenchendo os objetos, um a um, será mais rápido? Ou utilizando um `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Bem mais rápido. Fazendo na mão ou usando o Dapper serão as opções mais rápidas. Até o Entity Framework será bem melhor na maioria das vezes, especialmente o Core, ainda que um pouco mais complexo.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero, penso que com uma dessas opções conseguiremos ultrapassar o problema!

Comment: pense também na paginação, afinal se só os dados já pesam bastante, imagina um XML com mais de 1kk de registros...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis neste caso tem mesmo de ser um ficheiro só, tenha que tamanho tiver.

Comment: complicado... mas então pensaria em usar um datareader para ir lendo e escrevendo, sem armazenar tudo em memória

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `DataTable` foi uma ideia interessante, porém muito mal implementada, ela realmente carrega demais a memória.

Daí surgiu a necessidade de fazer um ORM de verdade e a Microsoft fez o [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) que é pesado, chato de usar no começo, é lento, mas funciona muito melhor. E o [EF Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) nem é tão ruim assim. Eu não sou fã dele por várias razões, mas é uma evolução.

Curiosamente logo no começo já tinha uma tecnologia melhor pra grande parte dos casos que é o [`DataReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), se só precisa ler dados, se não precisa estar *online* com o banco de dados ela é uma solução mais correta sempre. Na verdade mesmo que precise escrever e estar *online* o `DataTable` só é viável para coisas simples, e só porque o problema não é muito perceptível, não porque é bom.

O acesso direto ao [provedor do banco de dados](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou usar um ORM simples como o [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) são as opções mais rápidas que pode obter. O primeiro não tem camada extra, ele só te dá o acesso e você faz todo acesso na mão. Dá menos trabalho que imagina na maioria dos casos, ainda que tenha que cuida de certas coisas. O Dapper gera os objetos para você e consegue uma incrível performance mesmo assim e entrega mais pronto, oque pode se bem útil, especialmente se vai serializar.

Comment: +1 por citar Dapper, apesar de muitos "preguiçosos" dizerem que ele é muito verboso por escrever Sql no código nem ligam pela sua performasse que ele traz.

Comment: Eu acho o EF verboso :D Sabendo criar as abstrações certas o código fica muito menor c/ Dapper :D